# как при наведении добавить класс и убрать при наведени на другой блок

Tags: jquery

Как при наведении добавить класс и убирать при наведении на другой блок
Пример есть на сайте [tes.ru](https://tes.ru) в меню, когда мы наводим на один из пунктов и добавляется класс active, а убирается только тогда, когда мы наводим на другой пункт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("li").hover(
  function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
);
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Some Test</li>
  <li>Some Test</li>
  <li>Some Test</li>
  <li>Some Test</li>
  <li>Some Test</li>
  <li>Some Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!